# Need a Help for DB Design in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, associations

My project is for conducting surveys.

```
User has_many :companies
Company has_many :categories
```

and i need to conduct survey for each company.

```
 Survey has_many :categories
 Category has_many :questions
 Question has_many :answers;
```

Based on company category i need to display questions in each category.

Very Time consuming to design it. Please help me to do this.

Comment: "Very Time consuming to design it." - Stack Overflow is not meant to do your work for you. My advice would be to take a crack at it, and if you hit roadblocks, then come back for some specific, guided questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
User has_many :companies
Company has_many :users


Company has_many :company_categories (may be has one)
CompanyCategory has_many :companies


 Survey has_many :survay_categories (may be has one)
 SurveyCategory has_many :surveys

  Question has_many :question_categries (may be has one)
  QuestionCategory has_many :questions

 Question has_many :answers
 Answer has_one :question
```